# $\{(1/\sqrt\pi) (1-\sqrt{-1}x)^n/(1＋\sqrt{-1}x)^{n＋1}$ $(n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots)\}⊂L^2(-∞,∞)$ is complete normalized orthogonal basis

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces, orthogonality

1. I would like to prove $\{(1/\sqrt\pi) (1-\sqrt{-1}x)^{n}/(1＋\sqrt{-1}x)^{n＋1} \}$  $(n=0,\pm1,\pm2,\ldots)\}⊂L^2(-∞,∞)$ is complete normalized orthogonal basis.

I know

2. $\{1/\sqrt{2\pi}\exp(\sqrt{-1}nθ)\}$ is complete normalized orthogonal basis of $L^2(0,2π)$.

I heard I can solve 1 using 2.
How can I reduce 1 to 2 ?

The hint reads mebius transformation which sends real line to circle is effective.

Comment: `$\{a,b,c\}$` $\to\{a,b,c\}$

Comment: It's a bad idea to use $\sqrt{-1}$ since $-1$ has two complex roots (apart from the fact that makes the notation more complicated and error prone). What's wrong with using $i$?

Comment: Are you sure about this? These functions are not in $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ since they all have non-zero limits as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Maybe the basis should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi(1+x^2)}} (\frac{1-ix}{1+ix})^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \cdot \frac{(1-ix)^{n-1/2}}{(1+ix)^{n+1/2}}$?  Or perhaps the inner product used in case (1) should be $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\overline{f(x)} g(x)}{1+x^2}dx$?  Or something along those lines, haven't checked the details...

Comment: I missed, and I edited.